# アプリ実行時に設定した色が再現されない

Tags: android

androidのアプリを作っていて、color.xmlを作りそこに16進のカラーコードで好きな色を定義しました。
それらをテキスト等の色に設定したのですが、アプリ起動時には全て黒ないしはグレーになってしまいます。
元からあるColor.BLUEなどを入れると正常に青く表示されます。
RGBをべた打ちする方法もありますが、それだといちいち面倒くさくて出来ません。
元からある色以外を使う正しい方法はありますでしょうか。

EclipseでAndroid6.0を対象としています。
デバイスはXperia Z3 Tablet Compactです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

可能であれば実装しようとしているコードを提示されるとより良い回答が得られるかもしれません。

レイアウトファイル上で設定したいのであれば、以下のように指定することで可能です。

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/*1" />
```

プログラム上で設定したいのであれば、以下で指定することが可能です。

```
int colorValue = getResources().getColor(R.color.*1);
textView.setTextColor(colorValue);
```

*1 color.xmlで定義されたリソース名

---

追記

API Level 23ではgetColor(int)は非推奨メソッドとなっていました。
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)

APIリファレンスにはgetColor(int, Resources.Theme)を使用するように記載されています。
そのため、API Level 23以降で使用される場合は、getColor(int, Resources.Theme)を使用したほうが良いようです。
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)
Resources.ThemeはActivityが継承しているContextThemeWrapperにgetTheme()というAPIがありました。

```
int colorValue = -1;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    colorValue = getResources().getColor(R.color.*1, getTheme());
}else {
    colorValue = getResources().getColor(R.color.*1);
}
textView.setTextColor(colorValue);
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。R.をgetResources().getColor()の部分ができていなかったようでした。
しかし、「getColor()はgetResources()で使用すべきではありません」と警告が出てしまいます。API23からはContextCompat.getColor()を使うみたいなのですが、Eclipseの仕様なのかライブラリのandroid.support.v4をインポートできませんでした。何か解決策はありますか。

Comment: android.support.v4についてはライブラリを追加してなかったので、追加して解決しました。

Comment: APIリファレンスをしっかり確認できておらず申し訳ありません。API23以降でのgetColorについて追記致しました。互換性用のContextCompatについては別の質問をあげられているようなのでこちらには追記しません。